# Checking extensions on command parameters?

Tags: 14.04

So I'm running Ubuntu and what I want to do is check to see if `$1` and `$2` have certain extensions and if they exist. If they don't exist or have the wrong extension, the script ends. If they are right then it continues on with the code.

```
v1="$1"  
v2="$2"  

if [[ ! "$1"="*.txt" || "$2"="*.dat" || -e "$1" ]]; then  
echo "The file is ending"  
exit  
fi  

echo "Starting rest of code"
```

Thats how I would like it to work. Basically it assigns v1 and v2 to their respected command parameters. Then it runs an if statement to see if they meet the requirements. So for example, if `$1` is not a `.txt` file or if `$2` is not a `.dat` file or if `$1` doesn't exist, then it exits and displays `The File is ending`. However, if they do meet the requirements then the code continues and displays `Starting rest of code`.

As it stands right now, it wont continue, even if the right files are entered. Instead it exits no matter what.

Comment: You haven't said if you're using `bash` or `sh` for scripting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `=~` operator for regular expression matching:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
v1="$1"
v2="$2"
pat1='.*\.txt$'
pat2='.*\.dat$'
if [[ ! ($v1 =~ $pat1 && $v2 =~ $pat2 && -e $v1) ]]; then
    echo Ending program
    exit
fi
echo Continuing program
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing wrong is checking $1 against '.txt' where $1 will not contain only the extension but the whole file's name. For instance, if there's a file named

```
file1.txt
```

then $1 will hold `file1.txt` as value which is not equal to `.txt`.

What you should do is get file's extension first from $1 and then check them against type (without dot)

```
v1="$1"
v2="$2"
ext1=${v1##*.}
ext2=${v2##*.}
if [ "$ext1" != "txt" ] || [ "$ext2" != "dat" ] || [ ! -e "$1" ]; then
echo "The file is ending"
exit
fi
echo "Starting rest of code"
```

Comment: I tried this, but still doesn't work. Even if I do the right extensions as a command parameters(say the script is called file and i type ./file apple.txt random.dat), it still triggers the exit. So if I were to type that in, even though it satisfies everything in that it exists and has the right extensions, it will trigger the if statement and exit.

So for some reason, even correct command parameters are tiggering it.

Comment: Hi,  seems like there were syntax mistakes in script i posted .....i have corrected them check it now ....works.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking advantage of the `basename` command.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$(basename $1 .txt)" = "$1" -o "$(basename $2 .dat)" = "$2" ]; then
    echo "the file is ending" >&2
    exit 1
fi

echo "starting rest of code"
```

That code snippet tries stripping off a given extension and comparing the stripped version to the original:  if it's unchanged, then the filename does not have the given extension.  Note the inverted logic (if the strings are equal, then the filename doe *not* have the given extension).

This solution works with the standard shell or with bash.

Comment: It will also strip off any path.

Comment: True, the path also gets stripped.  If that's a problem, use something like `"$(basename $1 .txt)" = "$(basename $1)"` instead.